# How do I make a CSS rule that only affects text but not the image?

Tags: html, css, image, text, margin

I am using a php script that outputs the post like this:

````
<div class="postoutput">
  <p>
    <img src="content/xeon.png" alt="xeon.png">
    This is text, Xeon is great.```
  </p>
</div>
````

I can't touch the output but I can modify the CSS, is there way to add a margin that ONLY applies to the text using only CSS

The image is 100% wide and this is okay.

The desired goal is to **keep the image as it is** but make the text ONLY have a 10px margin on each side. Remember, I only have access to the CSS file.

Comment: What's preventing you from modifying the `php` file?

Comment: I am not allowed to touch it by the owner at the moment. So I made a copy of the CSS file and started making changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short... no you cannot apply css directly to the text in your case.

You could probably emulate something close though.

Assuming your image is fullwidth you could probably use something like:

```
p {
   padding:10px;
}

p > img {
   margin:-10px -10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, image is fullwidth (100%) This keeps the image at the edge of screen. After applying your suggestion the image now has a space on the right side of the screen. The text did move, so this is progress. Now I need to make the image go back to occupying the width of the screen.

Comment: You probably need `img {width:calc(100% + 20px );margin: 0 -10px ;}` ;)